# python socket delimited message

Tags: python, sockets, delimiter

I am receiving data from a source that does not specify the length of the data beforehand, and it never sends a consistent amount of data. Each message always starts with STR01 and always ends with END01 (these combinations of characters never appear inside of the message). The messages between the above start and end are in the form of: Alpha/something/something/something..../Beta. So a complete message might be:
fstffSTR01 khjhkj Alpha/something/something/something/Beta fdxgxfxEND01uvyvuv. I am interesting in storing the data between Alpha and Beta and append a csv file. My code until now is as follows:

```
def receive():
    while True:
            while True:
                global splitted_msg, end_msg
                full_msg = ''
                new_msg = True
                msg = clientsocket.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
                if len(msg) <= 0:
                    break
                if 'STR01' in msg:
                    print("New message started")
                    new_msg = False
                if 'END01' in msg:
                    new_msg = True
                    full_msg += msg
                try:
                    left = 'STR01'
                    right = 'END01'
                    end_msg=full_msg[full_msg.index(left) +len(left):full_msg.index(right)]
                    splitted_msg=re.split('Alpha|Beta', end_msg)
                    print(splitted_msg)
                    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=save_file)
                    thread2.start()
                except:
                    print("This is not a message!")
```

I am pretty new in python so bare with me!I have another def that stores the message (and append new ones) in txt form but it doesn't work as it should.Only the first message is "grabbed".

```
def save_file():
    current_date_time = datetime.now()
    with open('message.txt', 'a') as file:
        New_message = str(current_date_time) + "New Message:" + end_msg
        file.write(New_message)
        file.write("\n")
```

I could use anyone help for the code to be able to understand multiple messages and more importantly i could use any ideas for some code for me to be able to append a csv file with the values between Alpha and Beta.Thank you

Comment: You reset `full_msg` in each iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: Don't use global variables in multiple threads without proper concurrency control. Why use a thread here at all?